# Image inside container overflow inside

Tags: css, html, containers

Trying to make an image stretch and such inside a container, I can make it bigger then its container with overflow, but it gives me a scroll pad, I just want to make it bigger so I get the part oft he image I want inside the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/jo37L8cz/

```css
div.img_box{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;

background-color:blue;
      overflow:auto;
}
    .img_box img{
     width:500px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="img_box">
 <img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410195944/pokemon/images/archive/f/fc/20150101093541!025Pikachu_OS_anime_5.png" /></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to see the whole image? If you want the image to "crop" itself, the easiest thing to do is to set the image as a background on the containing DIV - you can do this using inline CSS.

Comment: I do not, I just want the portion of the image.

Comment: This will give you a portion of the image.. I will post code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.img_box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img_box img {
     width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but how would you change the image size since it's in a div style tag?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want a bit better? Thanks.

Comment: You could just use an image tag, set the size on that, but set the CSS of the containing DIV to overflow: hidden. This will clip the image, but at the same time, give you control over its size.

Comment: Right now, the image is perfectly overflowing inside the div container, but how would I change the width of that image to let's say 50px, I'm not sure how to do it since the image is in a "style"

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I don't want, I want to be able to control the size of the image inside the container and have it not overflow outside the container, only inside.

Comment: Use your original code, but change overflow: auto to overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like the following may work for you, using

```
background-size:cover
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/rgqvyrbr/1/

Comment: You can also change the height and width of the div to percentages and the image will scale to fit. What a happy dog! Yes you are YES YOU ARE!